# Nested asyncio coroutine with control flow back to caller

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

I have series of async steps to do which I want to put in a method. Each step generates a sub-result and induces a following async step, which again generates a sub-result until the final step is reached.

Take a look at my code:

```py
class TextDetector(Detector):
    lock: asyncio.Lock = asyncio.Lock()

    async def detect(self, input: TextDetectorInput) -> TextDetectorResult: 
        pass

class TextAugmentationProcedure(AugmentationProcedure):
    async def augment(
        self, input: AugmentationProcedureTextInput
    ) -> AugmentationProcedureTextOutput:
            pass
    
TextDetectorCoolDownAndResultType = Awaitable[Awaitable[ImageDetectorResult]]
RunTextDetectionType = AsyncIterator[tuple[DetectorIdentifier, TextDetector, TextDetectorCoolDownAndResultType]]
GetFilesTextType = AsyncIterator[tuple[InputFileIdentifier, TextInputFile, AugmentationProcedureTextOutput, RunTextDetectionType]]
CheckTextType = AsyncIterator[tuple[AugmentationProcedureIdentifier, TextAugmentationProcedure, GetFilesTextType]]

@dataclass
class TextTestCase(TestCase):

    inputs: dict[InputFileIdentifier, TextInputFile]

    augmentation_procedures: dict[AugmentationProcedureIdentifier, TextAugmentationProcedure]
    detectors: dict[DetectorIdentifier, TextDetector]
    
    async def get_files(self, augmentation_procedure: TextAugmentationProcedure) -> GetFilesTextType:
        for input_identifier, text_file in self.inputs.items():
            augmentation_input = await read_text_file(
                text_file.file_name, text_file.language
            )

            augmentation_output = await augmentation_procedure.augment(augmentation_input)
        
            detector_input = TextDetectorInput(
                        augmentation_output.language, augmentation_output.text
            )

            yield (input_identifier, text_file, augmentation_output, self.run_detection(detector_input))

    async def run_detection(self, detector_input: TextDetectorInput) -> RunTextDetectionType:
        for detector_identifier, detector in self.detectors.items():
            async def cooldown_and_detect(detector: TextDetector, detector_input: TextDetectorInput):
                # Acquire lock
                with detector.lock
                    # Cooldown
                    cooleddown = await detector.cooldown()
                    
                    return detector.detect(detector_input)
            
            yield (detector_identifier, detector, cooldown_and_detect(detector, detector_input))
    
    async def check(self) -> CheckImageType:
        for augmentation_procedure_identifier, augmentation_procedure in self.augmentation_procedures.items():
            yield (augmentation_procedure_identifier, augmentation_procedure, self.get_files(augmentation_procedure))
```

Basically, I want to get the sub-results when calling the method `check(...)` on an instance of `TextTestCase`. The interesting part is `run_detection()`. For each detector, the caller should be notified. After that, a lock is acquired. Then `detector.cooldown()` is called and awaited. If awaited, the caller should be notified and `detector.detect()` should be called. When the results are available, the caller should be notified and the lock should be released.

Currently, I call `check()` the following way:

```py
test_case = TextTestCase()

async for (augmentation_procedure_identifier, augmentation_procedure, augmentation_results) in test_case.check():
    async for (file_identifier, image_file, augmentation_output_awaitable, detectors) in augmentation_results:
        
        results.append([image_file.file_name, str(procedure), "Augmenting...", ""])
        live.update(update_table_with_results(results))

        async for (detector_identifier, detector, cooldown_awaitable) in detectors:
            try:
                detection_awaitable = await cooldown_awaitable
                detection_result = await detection_awaitable
            
                # TODO: Do stuff here
            except:
                pass
                # Error occured
                # TODO: print error
```

Because `cooldown_and_detect()` *returns* an awaitable, `detector.detect()`, the context manager obviously releases the lock as soon as the awaitable is returned, i.e. after `detector.cooldown()` was awaited and `detector.detect()` was triggered. But I want to release it after `detector.detect()` was awaited, but still I want to pass the control flow to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you want is a bit confuse to understand from the code above, but everything should be possible by adding proper callbacks . I.e. if your tasks can be described in a plain acyclic flow which could run in parallel, you should just use `await`  and context managers all the way down, and just use either an asyncio.TaskGroup, or a call to `gather` with all the "root level" tasks you want to run in parallel.

Otherwise, since you want to custom manage intermediate resources, like the ones guarded by your `lock`, you can call `acquire` explicitly, and release the lock on done callbacks of the respective steps, instead of using the lock as a context manager ( `with` block), or uncondtionally releasing it on a `finally` block.

As I wrote earlier, your example appears to be a bit more contrived than it could so that a nice example based on your code could be written - please read about posting  a [minimal reproducible example before asking your next question -](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

That said, soemthing along the code bellow for your inner `cooldown_and_detect` co-routine could have the effect you want, if I could understand you correctlyL

```
async def cooldown_and_detect(detector, detector_input: TextDetectorInput):
    # Acquire lock
    await detector.lock.acquire()
    try:    # Cooldown
        cooleddown = await detector.cooldown()
    except Exception as error:
        # something wrong with cooldown - release lcok
        detector.lock.release()
        raise
    detector_task = asyncio.create_task(detector.detect(detector_input))
    detector_task.add_done_callback(lambda task: detector.lock.release())
    return detector_task
```